# Protecting access to packaged_task

Tags: c++11, concurrency

I think this is a simple question about shared access to std::packaged_task.

In the code below I am not sure if I need a mutex to protect access to the object 'p'.

It seems that I should, since p.operator() may be called in the background thread at the same time as p.get_future() in the main thread. Or is this sort of access to a packaged_task object already protected in some way?

```
static double f(int a, int b) { return a * b; }

int main()
{
    // Execute f() "immediately" in another thread
    //std::future<double> result = std::async(f, 2, 3);
    //std::cout << result.get() << std::endl;

    // Deferred execution of f()
    std::packaged_task<double(int, int)> p(f);
    std::thread tt([&p]{ /* processing ... */; p(2, 3); });
    std::cout << p.get_future().get() << std::endl;
    tt.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand (the N3337 draft of the) the standard, everything should be well as long as the shared state is created and a future is not yet fetched.

The packed_task ctoring and the future fetching are sequential in your code; thus I understand that the possible collision you mention should do no harm; at least there is no such problem mentioned in item 14 below.

N3337 §30.6.9.1 [futures.task.members]

has

> 1[...]
> `template <class F> packaged_task(F&& f);`
>
> [...]
> 3 Effects: constructs a new packaged_task object with a shared state[...]
> [...]
>
> 11[...]
> `future<R> get_future();`
> [...]
> 13 Throws: a future_error object if an error occurs.
> 14 Error conditions:
> — future_already_retrieved if get_future has already been called on a packaged_task object with the same shared state as *this.
> — no_state if *this has no shared state.